# check if element exists on the sub-list

Tags: haskell, monads, type-mismatch

I can have many Figures on my list. Each Figure can have many Rectangles on its list. I have a problem with my function checkNewRectangleId - this function should ask user about new rectangle id until he write really new id and then it should return this id - but I have an error: couldn't match expected type IO t against inferred type Maybe figureType line `(Figure id width height rectangles) <- findFigure idFigure x` in my function - could you help ?

```
import IO
import Char
import System.Exit
import Maybe
import Data.Time.Calendar
import System.Time


checkNewRectangleId :: Int -> [FigureType] -> IO Int
checkNewRectangleId idFigure x  = do
    idRectangle <- getInt "Give me new rectangle id: "
    (Figure id width height rectangles) <- findFigure idFigure x
    if isJust (findRectangle idRectangle rectangles) then do
            putStrLn ("We have yet rectangle with id " ++ show idRectangle)
            checkNewRectangleId idFigure x
        else return idRectangle


data FigureType = Figure Int Int Int [RectangleType] deriving(Show, Read)

data RectangleType = Rectangle Int CalendarTime deriving(Show, Read)

findFigure :: Int -> [FigureType] -> Maybe FigureType
findFigure _ [] = Nothing
findFigure n ((Figure id width height rectangles) : xs) =
    if n == id then Just (Figure id width height rectangles)
    else findFigure n xs

findRectangle :: Int -> [RectangleType] -> Maybe RectangleType
findRectangle _ [] = Nothing
findRectangle n ((Rectangle id date) : xs) =
    if n == id then Just (Rectangle id date)
    else findRectangle n xs

isInt i = not (null i) && all isDigit i

getInt :: String -> IO Int
getInt q = do
    putStr q;
    i <- getLine
    if isInt i == False then do
            putStrLn "Bad number"
            getInt q
        else return (read i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say `idFigure` is guaranteed to exist, you can use `fromJust` in the `Data.Maybe` module to convert a `Maybe FigureType` into a `FigureType`:

```
let (Figure id width height rectangles) = fromJust $ findFigure idFigure x
```

Comment: In my opinion, if you are already in a `let` then pattern matching with `Just` looks cleaner than `fromJust $`.   For example `let Just (Figure id width height rectangles) = findFigure idFigure x`

Answer (score 1):

`findFigure` operates in the Maybe monad, but `checkNewRectangleId` operates in the IO monad. Haskell will not automatically translate failures (or successes) in one monad into failures (or successes) in another, because the types don't match. So, you have to ask yourself the question, what do you want to happen if `findFigure` fails to find anything?

Comment: idFigure always exists because I check it before I call function checkNewRectangleId. idRectangle can not exist and in this situation program should call again checkNewRectangleId idFigure x.